# Bounds on horizontal minima of the Riemann zeta function

Tags: nt.number-theory, riemann-zeta-function

It is known that $\zeta(s)$ has an infinity of zeros in the strip $0<\sigma<1$ and that those zeros become closer together as $t\rightarrow\infty$. More precisely, Littlewood showed that there is a zero $\rho=\beta+i\gamma$ with $|\gamma-t|\in O(1/\log\log\log t)$.

A positive proportion of these zeros are known to have $\beta=1/2$, but $\zeta(1/2+it)$ is unbounded. In fact, $\zeta(\sigma+it)$ is bounded as $t\rightarrow\infty$ only if $\sigma>1+\delta$, $\delta>0$ fixed.

On the other hand, there seem to be good reasons to expect that
$$f(t)=\min_{0\leq\sigma\leq 1} |\zeta(s)|$$
approaches zero as $t\rightarrow\infty$. One reason is that zeros of $\zeta(s)$ are rather differently distributed than those of $\zeta(s)-z$ for any other value of $z$.

I would like to argue that $f(t)\rightarrow 0$ here, but my approach is incomplete. In fact, I would like to conjecture that, for every $\epsilon>0$, we have $$f(t)\in O (\log^{\Theta(t) -1+\epsilon}t),$$ 
where $\Theta(t)=\max\{\beta:\gamma<t\}  $.

My questions are as follows: is anything at all non-trivial known about upper bounds on $f(t)$ and/or who has studied it? Does anyone have any computational data supporting this conjecture? Thanks!

Comment: I would be surprised if this were true. For certain values of t zeta(sigma+ i t) is almost real for 0<sigma<1 and take large values  >1. For example for t=87568424.95851 the minimum of the absolute value is >6 (more or less).

Comment: I have no proof, it is only a guess after seeing many x-ray plots, T. Kotnik has given many of these ordinates.

Answer (score 2):

This is not exactly an answer, but too long for a comment.

Perhaps I have not been sufficiently clear in the comments. In the paper:
T. Kotnik, Computational estimation of the order of $\zeta(1/2+i t)$,
Math. of Comp. 73 (2003) 949-956
it is shown how to get values $t$ where  $|\zeta(1/2+it)|$ is large.

Many (almost all) of these values of $t$ are near a Gram point.
The x-ray shows that these Gram points are places where a real line 
(one where zeta is real) hit the critical line. Precisely the real line
goes from $\sigma=+\infty$. On these lines $\zeta(s)$ is real and $>1$.
What the x-ray's show is that the points signaled by Kotnik are those in which
these lines are almost parallel to the real line. So that at these height
$t$ the value $\zeta(\sigma+it)$ is almost real for $0<\sigma<1$. By the election 
of the lines $|\zeta(1/2+it)|>>1$. This is the what  Kotnik is searching, and we know
that $\Re\zeta(\sigma+it) >1$, because these points are almost on the real line.

Therefore we expect that 
$$\limsup_{t\to\infty} f(t)\ge 1.$$
Of course this contradicts the conjecture above, except if you assume that 
$\Theta(t)\to1$, which contradicts the RH.

For example I take one of the values given by Kotnik (and he has means to get these
values apparently without limit).
I take $t=21559062801.941668$ where he reported
$Z(t)=-192.996$.  And compute the values 
$$\zeta(it)=410676.057+11579.014 \cdot i$$
$$\zeta(0.1+it)=67487.871+ 1567.236\cdot i$$
$$\zeta(0.2+it)=12335.222+225.398\cdot i$$
$$\zeta(0.3+it)=2584.380+37.231\cdot i$$
$$\zeta(0.4+it)=640.801+7.986\cdot i$$
$$\zeta(0.5+it)=192.982+2.341\cdot i$$
$$\zeta(0.6+it)=71.315+0.841\cdot i$$
$$\zeta(0.7+it)=32.010+0.315\cdot i$$
$$\zeta(0.8+it)=17.005+0.101\cdot i$$
$$\zeta(0.9+it)=10.355+0.010\cdot i$$
$$\zeta(1+it)=7.013-0.027\cdot i$$

As I said the values are 'almost real' and the absolute value 
$|\zeta(1/2+it)|>7$.  But I have taken any of the values of Kotnik.

Comment: This is very interesting. Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean that there is a way of determining arbitrarily large t for which a curve on which zeta is real and increasing (from right to left) is sufficiently nearby to guarantee that the lower bound holds?

Comment: Not exactly. (a) Kotnik explains a procedure by which he obtains the points $t_k$ where $|Z(t_k)|$ has a record.  This records are infinite because $Z(t)$ is not bounded. (b) I observed that at these points a real line of zeta cross almost perpendicular to the critical line. I know that at these lines zeta is real and $>1$.  (c) the two previous points are reasons to suspect that $\limsup f(t) > 1$.

Comment: My experience with x-rays of zeta. Difficult to explain without graphs and a common language(I am not English speaker) make me suspect that (b) is not a coincidence. The near parallell line is associated to big values of $Z(t)$ and some other things.

Comment: Finally. This is all based on the computation of $Z(t)$ that are possible only for $t$ small. I may be very wrong, (as those that assume the RH), because we ignore how zeta behave at higher values. Say when $S(t)$ is of the order of 1000.

Comment: So I will say that yes, if you give me a $t_0$ on the range of possible computations I will give you a $t>t_0$, where your $f(t)>1$.

Comment: Indeed it seems a good reason, provided that there are real lines of arbitrary height that do not intersect imaginary ones. It appears that they alternate, do you think this can be proved? The

Comment: Yes they alternate, this is easy to prove. But a real line where zeta > 1 need not to be almost straight. This happens at the points given by Kotnik, but this is only an observation. I do not see a proof.

Answer (score 2):

Not a compete answer, but observations on the value of $\sigma$ for which the minimum occurs.  Throughout I'm assuming the Riemann Hypothesis.

In *"Zeros of $\zeta^\prime(s)$ and the Riemann Hypothesis"*, Spira proves that the Riemann Hypothesis holds if and only if $|\zeta(s)|$ is increasing as $\sigma$ decreases from $1/2$ to $-\infty$ for $t\gg 1$ (He seems to prove $t>165$.)  So it suffice to consider the minimum over $1/2\le \sigma\le 1$.

From now on we assume $\zeta(1/2+it)\ne 0$ (else the minimum over $\sigma$ is already $0$ for that $t$.)  Then $|\zeta(\sigma+i t)|>0$, and so $\ln|\zeta(\sigma+i t)|$ is defined.  Since $\ln$ is increasing and preserves inequalities, the same $\sigma$ minimizes both $|\zeta(\sigma+i t)|$ and $\ln|\zeta(\sigma+i t)|$.  There are three possibilities:

I: $\ln|\zeta(\sigma+i t)|$ is increasing on $1/2\le \sigma\le 1$ and the minimum occurs at $\sigma=1/2$.

II: $\ln|\zeta(\sigma+i t)|$ is decreasing on $1/2\le \sigma\le 1$ and the minimum occurs at $\sigma=1$.

III: $\ln|\zeta(\sigma+i t)|$ has a local minimum on $(1/2,1)$.  (Conceivably, the global minimum may still occur at an endpoint.)  This is the case in which
$$
\frac{d}{d\sigma}\ln|\zeta(s)|=0
\Leftrightarrow \frac{\partial}{\partial \sigma} \text{Re}(\log(\zeta(s)))=0
\Leftrightarrow \text{Re}\left(\frac{\zeta^\prime(s)}{\zeta(s)}\right)=0.
$$

This latter happens when either

IIIa: $\zeta^\prime(s)=0$, or

IIIb: $\arg\left(\frac{\zeta^\prime(s)}{\zeta(s)}\right)=\pm \pi/2.$

The zeros of $\zeta^\prime(s)$ occur discretely (just as do the zeros of $\zeta(s)$).  Meanwhile the level curves for $\arg=\pm \pi/2$ will connect the zeros of $\zeta^\prime/\zeta$ (i.e. the zeros of $\zeta^\prime(s)$) with the poles of $\zeta^\prime/\zeta$ (i.e. the zeros of $\zeta(s)$ on the critical line.)

Titchmarsh shows that $\zeta(s)\ne 0$ for $\sigma>3$, and zeros with $\sigma>1$ do exist.  But Spira shows in *"Zeros of $\zeta^\prime(s)$ in the critical strip"* that 'most' zeros are close to $\sigma=1/2$ (in the sense that the number of zeros with $\sigma>1/2+\delta$, $t<T$ is only O(T).)  Lots of research has been done on the clustering of the zeros of $\zeta^\prime$ near the critical line.

Edit: For $t\gg1$, possibility I above can not occur. For if it did, then combined with Spira's result above, we would have that $\sigma=1/2$ is a local minimum.  But the formula for the logarithmic derivative
$$
\frac{\zeta^\prime(s)}{\zeta(s)}=\log(2\pi)-1-C/2-\frac{1}{s-1}-\frac{\Gamma^\prime(s/2+1)}{2\Gamma(s/2+1)}+\sum_{\rho}\left(\frac{1}{s-\rho}+\frac{1}{\rho}\right),
$$
along with Stirling's formula, gives that 
$$
\text{Re}\frac{\zeta^\prime}{\zeta}(1/2+it)\sim -\log(t/2)/2,
$$
and in particular is not $0$.

Case II above should correspond to zeros of $\zeta^\prime(s)$ with $\sigma>1$, or consecutive zeros of $\zeta$ with no zero of $\zeta^\prime$ in between (for otherwise the horizontal line $t=\text{const.}$ should cross a level curve $\arg=\pm \pi/2$.)  This latter phenomenon happens at intervals on average of $2\pi/\log(2)\approx 9.064$, due to the different asymptotics of the zeros of $\zeta$ and $\zeta^\prime$.

Final edit: the graphic below shows $t$ on the vertical axis, and, on the horizontal axis, the Hardy function $Z(t)$ (in purple) and the value of $\sigma$ which minimizes $f(t)$.  Also marked on the vertical axis are the zeros of $Z(t)$ (in black).  The $t$ which correspond to zeros of $\zeta^\prime(s)$ are marked in red when $1/2<\sigma<1$, and in green when $\sigma\ge1$.  [Thanks to Ricky Farr for computation of zeros of $\zeta^\prime$.]  The data illustrates that minima occuring at $\sigma=1$ tend to be associated to consecutive zeros of $\zeta$ with either no intervening zero of $\zeta^\prime$, or a zero of $\zeta^\prime$ with $\sigma\ge 1$.

[image] [<sup>(source)</sup>](http://web.math.ucsb.edu/~stopple/mopic.jpg)

Comment: I'll make this a comment since it's speculative.  I think the $t$ of type II above will be associated to large gaps between zeros, and large values of $|\zeta(1/2+it)|$.  Titchmarsh Theorem 8.12 specializes to say that for any $\alpha<1/2$, there exist arbitrarily large values of $t$ for which $|\zeta(1/2+it)|>\exp(\log(t)^\alpha))$.  Now for those same $t$, $|\zeta(1+it)|$ will be smaller, but I don't think it's plausible that these values will tend to $0$.

Comment: Somehow I didn't know you had given this answer until just now. On first reading I think it will take me a while to digest, but for the moment I would like to thank you.

Comment: I can email you the graphics if you want a closer look.

Comment: Please do- my email address is k.p.q.smith@gmail.com.

Answer (score 2):

The following paper deals with the behavior of the modulus of the Zeta function in the critical strip along horizontal lines:

- MR1986257 (2004c:11152)  Saidak, Filip ;  Zvengrowski, Peter . On the modulus of the Riemann zeta function in the critical strip.
  Math. Slovaca  53  (2003),  no. 2, 145--172.

See also the slightly related paper

- MR2857985 (Reviewed)  Srinivasan, Gopala Krishna ;  Zvengrowski, P.  On the horizontal monotonicity of |Γ(s)|.
  Canad. Math. Bull.  54  (2011),  no. 3, 538--543.

See also [arXiv:1205.2773](http://de.arxiv.org/pdf/1205.2773.pdf)